# Use credentials from terraformrc file in modules

Tags: terraform

I have a terraformrc file setup as described [here](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file). It contains a gitlab token and is used to fetch a terraform module from an on-prem gitlab instance. However, I also need this token inside my actual terraform module for the [gitlab provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs).

At the moment I have said terraformrc file and in addition I add the access token as command line argument to use it inside my terraform modules. It seems odd to manage a token at two different location: Is it possible to reference the content of the terraformrc file within my project?

Comment: Is your file named with a leading `.` and in your home directory?

Comment: This question is somewhat unclear because you should not need a `terraformrc` credentials file for either of those scenarios. Those can both be performed with a variety of git credential helpers, environment variables, config files, etc. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The credentials in the CLI Configuration (the "terraformrc" file is an example of a "CLI Configuration" file) are only for Terraform-native Services, as described in [Internals: Remote Service Discovery](https://www.terraform.io/internals/remote-service-discovery).

GitLab has an implementation of [the module registry protocol](https://www.terraform.io/internals/module-registry-protocol), which is one of the Terraform-native Services and so the credentials in your CLI configuration apply to those requests.

However, the credentials in the CLI configuration don't apply to any protocols that are not "Terraform-native", which is to say protocols that are defined by some other system outside of Terraform. That includes the GitLab provider, because that provider implement's GitLab's own API, which has [its own authentication scheme](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication), separate from the Terraform-native one.

Therefore you will need to configure these two separately, even though by coincidence they may happen to accept the same token because both of these distinct protocols are implemented by the same remote server. There is no way to automatically use a Terraform-specific credential to authenticate to a non-Terraform protocol. The GitLab provider documentation describes some different ways you can configure credentials for that provider to use.